# querystring and request in node js

Tags: node.js, query-string

when I use the keywords querystring and request in my program it says querystring not defined and request not defined respectively. Is there any prerequisite installation that is to be done?

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: Are you using express.js or it is only node?

Answer (score 2):

querystring is a native module so you don't need to install it. You can find it's doc [here](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html)

But you have to install the request module by typing this command :

```
npm i request
```

After that you have to require those modules in your code like this :

```
var request = require('request');
var querystring = require('querystring');
```